# How to make parallel programming with input values in java

Tags: java, multithreading, multiprocessing

I implement a recommendation algorithm in Java program.

However, I have serious problems. The dataset is too large and it's computation is too slow. So, I need to do parallel programming in Java.

For example,

```
for (int i=0; i < 10000000 ; i++) { ~~~ }
```

I want to split this sentences such as

```
process 1: for (int i=0; i < 10000 ; i++)

process 2: for (int i=10001; i < 20000 ; i++)

process 3: for (int i=20001; i < 30000 ; i++)
```

...

I know similar methods [in Python](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html). How to do parallel programming in Java?

Comment: You mean threads? And isn't the parallel programming when people code parallely? Just like pair programming.. but parallel! Just use Java Threads

Comment: You might consider using Java 8's parallel streams....

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final long countUntil;

        MyRunnable(long countUntil) {
                this.countUntil = countUntil;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                long sum = 0;
                for (long i = 1; i < countUntil; i++) {
                        sum += i;
                }
                System.out.println(sum);
        }
}



public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                // We will store the threads so that we can check if they are done
                List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
                // We will create 500 threads
                for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                        Runnable task = new MyRunnable(10000000L + i);
                        Thread worker = new Thread(task);
                        // We can set the name of the thread
                        worker.setName(String.valueOf(i));
                        // Start the thread, never call method run() direct
                        worker.start();
                        // Remember the thread for later usage
                        threads.add(worker);
                }
                int running = 0;
                do {
                        running = 0;
                        for (Thread thread : threads) {
                                if (thread.isAlive()) {
                                        running++;
                                }
                        }
                        System.out.println("We have " + running + " running threads. ");
                } while (running > 0);

        }
}
```

i got it from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html)